# Redirect route and display message

Tags: remix.run

I am wondering if there is a way to redirect a route or return a `Response` with a data and fetch it at another page with the `loader` function.

Basically I am trying to create a new object with a form and redirect to another page where I wanted to display a creation success message.

Here is a form page example:

I am trying to send the message in the `Response` body.

```js
import { ActionFunction, Form } from "remix";

export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  // const formData = await request.formData();

  return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Hello world!" }), {
    status: 303,
    headers: {
      Location: "/new-page",
    },
  });
};

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form method="post">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And at the `NewPage` I needed to know if there is a way to get the message on the redirect response.

```js
import { ActionFunction } from "remix";

export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();

  // Get message here

  return {
    message: "",
  };
};

export default function NewPage() {
  return <div>New Page</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a good use case for session flash message

https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#sessionflashkey-value

The documentation provides a good example, but the idea behind that is :

- Get your form data in Index's action
- Store the stringify data in a session cookie flash message
- Return a response, using redirect function (helper imported from remix, that make a Response redirect for you)
- In NewPage's loader, read the session cookie message and return it. Don't forget to commit your session, it'll delete this flash message for you
- Use useLoaderData hook in your component to get the loader's return data

```js
//sessions.server.ts
import { createCookieSessionStorage } from "remix";

// https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#createcookiesessionstorage
const { getSession, commitSession, destroySession } =
  createCookieSessionStorage({
    cookie: {
      name: "__session",
      secrets: ["r3m1xr0ck5"], // should be a process.env.MY_SECRET
      sameSite: "lax",
    },
  });
```

```js
import { ActionFunction, Form } from "remix";
import { getSession, commitSession } from "./sessions";

export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  // const formData = await request.formData();
  // Get session
  const session = await getSession(
    request.headers.get("Cookie")
  );

  session.flash("myMessageKey", "Hello world!");

  return redirect("/new-page", {
    headers: {
      "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session),
    },
  });
};

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form method="post">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
import { LoaderFunction } from "remix";
import { getSession, commitSession } from "./sessions";

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();

  // Get message here
  const session = await getSession(
    request.headers.get("Cookie")
  );
  const message = session.get("myMessageKey") || null;

  return json(
    { message },
    {
      headers: {
        "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session), //will remove the flash message for you
        // "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session, { maxAge: SESSION_MAX_AGE }), //re set max age if you previously set a max age for your sessions.
      },
    }
  );
};

export default function NewPage() {
  const { message } = useLoaderData();
  return <div>New Page {message}</div>;
}
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me. Somehow `commitSession()` sets the previous `max-age` to 0, hence I get logged out. Do I need to also set `max-age` everytime?

Comment: Yes, without that the session expire immediately if your previous session had a max age

Comment: Well, that sucks. I set `max-age` on login where I have access to a `rememberUser` value from a form, but if it resets it everytime, would I need to persistently store that value for later access then?

Comment: not necessarily, just re set max age on every commitSession you do.
To help me, i do some helper that wrap commitSession and set max age for me (max age is a const in my code base).
If it helps, this a the code I use daily : https://github.com/rphlmr/supa-fly-stack/blob/4bce6d7e2fe5c87b34b5913f49f9929f463818e0/app/core/auth/session.server.ts#L71

Comment: love this. [alternative article](https://www.jacobparis.com/content/remix-form-toast#using-a-cookie-session-storage) i've found helpful for the same thing. i went with cookie session storage method with `sonner` & [a custom toast component](https://github.com/jacobparis-insiders/jacobparis.com/issues/3).